# Is there any mongodb client that accepts SSL

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I am using Robomongo but I am unable to connect to my mongodb since it is ssl enabled. So, I am currently connecting through cmd, but it has its limitations like page buffer and I am missing the UI experience.

Comment: which version of robomongo you are using?

Answer (score 1):

RoboMongo version 10 has support for SSL, use this version.

More info - http://blog.robomongo.org/robomongo-rc10/